# A question about a fast proof of determinant properties (row becomes column)

Tags: matrices

New matrix's ith column is old matrix's ith row.
How to prove quickly that the determinant of 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{n1} & x_{n2} & x_{n3} & \dots  & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}

is equal to that of 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{21} & x_{31} & \dots  & x_{n1} \\
    x_{12} & x_{22} & x_{32} & \dots  & x_{n2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    x_{1n} & x_{2n} & x_{2n} & \dots  & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}

? I can think of using mathematical induction and cofactor expansion. But is there a simpler proof (using properties of determinant from "elementary row operations")?

Comment: I don't think there is exceptional fast way. One has to notice that the mapping is preserved, so I guess showing that it works for a 3x3 Matrix and then noticing a generalization via induction for a n x n matrix seems the fastest to me..

Comment: The matrix obtained by "row becomes column" has a name: "transpose". Look for "deteminant of transpose"

Answer (score 0):

Hint: ( not a proof, but an intuition).

An elementary row operation is represented by an elementary matrix $T$ that operates at the left of a matrix $A$ as $TA$. The same elementary matrix when operates on the right represents the corresponding elementary column operation.

We can operate a set of elementary row operations $T_i$ on $A$ that transform $A$ to a diagonal matrix $ (T_1\cdots T_i) A=D$ and, from the properties of determinants we have: $\det D=\det(T_1\cdots T_i)\det A$.

The same sequence of elementary matrices applied right to the transpose of $A$, gives the same diagonal matrix: $ A^T(T_1\cdots T_i) =D$ so we have:
$$
\det(T_1\cdots T_i)\det A=\det A^T\det(T_1\cdots T_i)
$$ 
and we find the result.